# I cant install the package kneed

Tags: python

I installed in a local environment in anaconda (JupyterLab) the package `kneed` with the command `conda install -c conda-forge kneed`. Previously I installed in the same environment the packages `jupyter,kneed, matplotlib, numpy, pandas ,seaborn, scikit-learn`.
While importing these modules in a jupyter notebook I get an error message saying that kneed is not installed:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kneed'
```

I have `Python 3.9.7` installed.

To the contrary, when I check on the command line within the environment the same commands I have no problem. It seems as if Jupyter notebook is missing the information of the new installation of `kneed.`
Do you have any suggestion ? Many thanks.

Comment: Please see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56590861/kneed-installation-issue-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-kneed

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to say that I already tried this, `!pip install --upgrade kneed`. It did not make any difference.

Comment: DO you start anaconda prompt with run as administrator? I don't know this work for your problem but when I can't install package, this way works.

Comment: I start it typing in anaconda-navigator on the command line. Then I go over to JupyterLab. There I activate an environment with conda acivate base, I do not know what is anaconda prompt.

Comment: Please read carefully this document: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/verify-install/. if you works with  Windows: Click Start, search, then select Anaconda Prompt from the menu and right click on and select Run as  administrator when open anaconda prompt  type: conda install -c conda-forge kneed then enter.

Comment: Thanks. I have Ubuntu, I think it is the only way to start anaconda in ubuntu. It is in line with that document.

Comment: I added something on my post.

Comment: Since you've tried other stuff, it wouldn't hurt to try **in a cell in your notebook** `%conda install -c conda-forge kneed`. And then try the import again to see if it worked. If it didn't work, then try **in a cell in your notebook** `%pip install kneed`. Please read about using the modern magics [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). You no longer want to use an exclamation point with `pip` or `conda` when using them in a notebook. The newer, modern magics are more reliable.